# No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from the literal `1'

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

```
create_subseq size xs = 
  if (length xs) == size
  then [ [ x | x <- s] | s <- xs] 
  else [ [ i | i <- subxs] | subxs <- (take size xs)] ++ create_subseq size (tail xs)
```

I keep trying to run this code in ghci with the line below however I get the error below

```
create_subseq 3 [1,2,3,4]

No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from the literal `1'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t0])
In the expression: 1
In the second argument of `create_subseq', namely `[1, 2, 3, 4]'
In the expression: create_subseq 3 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the type of `create_subseq` in `ghci`, you get this:

```
*Main> :t create_subseq
create_subseq :: Int -> [[t]] -> [[t]]
```

In other words the second argument should be a list of lists of something, but you've only passed a list of numbers. `ghci` then tries to interpret the numbers as lists, but it can't, hence the error message.

If you want to know why `create_subseq` takes a list of lists, look at the list comprehensions you've written. They each assume that the original argument `xs` is a list, and that when you look at an element in the list `xs` you have another list that you can write a nested list comprehension on.

Comment: Shoot, any idea how I can fix this. I'm new to haskell, I really want to get into it but it is giving me so much stress. I want to get a list of lists as the return value that represents each subsequence of length specified by size.Your help would be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: I don't really know what your code is supposed to do. You can fix the specific error you have by passing a list of lists, e.g. `create_subseq 3 [[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[5,6]]` but this crashes if the outer list is anything other than length 3. 

You might be better off asking for help on #haskell on Freenode IRC or on the Haskell beginners mailing list (http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners), as StackOverflow isn't really a good place for leading people through problems step by step.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of sub lists of size size from an input list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, I starting to figure out haskell. I like it so far, I hope to keep learning.

```
-- Program will read a file with a 1000 digit number. The goal of the program
-- is to find a sequence within that number that is 13 digits long and has
-- the largest product. This program is not safe to run on 32 bit machines
-- you will run into number overflow and get inaccurate results

import System.Environment
import Data.Char

create_sub_seq :: Int->[Int]->[[Int]]
create_sub_seq n xs = if length xs == n
              then [xs]
              else [[i | i <- take n xs]]++create_sub_seq n (tail xs)

prod :: [Int]->Int
prod xs = foldl (*) 1 xs 

getIntArray :: [Char] -> [Int]
getIntArray xs = [digitToInt i |i <- xs, not(i=='\n')]


max_sub_seq :: ([Int]->Int)->[[Int]]->[Int]
max_sub_seq  f [] = []
max_sub_seq  f (xs:xxs) = if (f b) > (f xs) 
                  then b
                  else xs
                  where b=max_sub_seq f xxs

main = do [f] <- getArgs
      s <- readFile f

--    print( create_sub_seq 4 (getIntArray s))
      print( max_sub_seq prod (create_sub_seq 13 (getIntArray s)) )
      print( prod ( max_sub_seq prod (create_sub_seq 13 (getIntArray s)) ) )
```

Comment: If you need 64-bit integers, you should specify them explicitly, using the type `Int64` from `Data.Int`. This may produce slow code on a 32-bit system, but at least it will be correct; on a 64-bit system it should generate the same code as just using `Int`. Of course, you should only use them where they're needed, and should be careful with conversions. There's no need for you to define `prod`; just use `product`.

Comment: Also, I really don't think your `create_sub_seq` looks like it's doing anything sensible. What exactly is it *supposed* to do?